# Problem with nested Dict in Python (KeyError)

Tags: python, django

I try to append data to a complicated Dictionary in Python.
The Structure is given, i cannot change this.

Example Code:

```
class AutoVivification(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def vorgang(self, lead):

        payload = AutoVivification()

        payload['antragsteller1'] = {
            'personendaten': {
                'anrede': lead.salutation,
                'vorname': lead.firstname,
                'nachname': lead.lastname,
                'email': lead.email,
                'telefonPrivat': lead.phone,
                'geburtsdatum': str(lead.birthdate)
            },
            'wohnsituation': {
                'anschrift': {
                    'strasse': lead.address,
                    'plz': lead.zip,
                    'ort': lead.city
                }
            },
            'beschaeftigung': {
                'beschaeftigungsart': lead.employment
            }
        }


        if lead.employment == 'ARBEITER':
            payload['antragsteller1']['beschaeftigung']['arbeiter']['beschaeftigungsverhaeltnis']['nettoeinkommenMonatlich'] = str(lead.income)

        elif lead.employment == 'ANGESTELLTER':
            payload['antragsteller1']['beschaeftigung']['angestellter']['beschaeftigungsverhaeltnis']['nettoeinkommenMonatlich'] = str(lead.income)

        elif lead.employment == 'ARBEITSLOSER':
            payload['antragsteller1']['beschaeftigung']['arbeitsloser']['sonstigesEinkommenMonatlich'] = str(lead.income)
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 'angestellter'
```

Why it is not possible to append 'angestellter' at the second elif statement?
And how would it be possible?

Comment: It's not possible because `angestellter` doesn't exist in that dict.

Comment: Yes i know, i would like to create it automatically when it doesn't exist

Comment: Just set it. `payload['antragsteller1']['beschaeftigung']['angestellter'] = {'beschaeftigungsverhaeltnis': {'nettoeinkommenMonatlich': str(lead.income)}}`

Comment: Yeah, that's possible - but i thought it would exist a easier solution because i need to set a lot more. But this is now my solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
payload['antragsteller1']['beschaeftigung']['angestellter']['beschaeftigungsverhaeltnis']['nettoeinkommenMonatlich'] = str(lead.income)
```

This statement is actually:

```
some_dict = payload['antragsteller1']['beschaeftigung']['angestellter']['beschaeftigungsverhaeltnis']
some_dict['nettoeinkommenMonatlich'] = str(lead.income)
```

So before you set the last value you are retrieving the existing keys-values pairs that do not exists.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work: KeyError: 'angestellter'.
I don't wont create every key manually because i need a lot more if statement...
I would like to create automatically when it doesn't exist